# Magento 2 Minicart error

Tags: magento-2.1

We are having a KO error with our minicart in **Magento 2.1**

The error we are seeing is :

```
knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "attr: function (){return {
                       id:'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty','data-cart-item':item_id,'data-item-qty':qty,'data-cart-item-id':product_sku} }"
```

> Message: product_sku is not defined

Does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Comment: Is there any customization which related to mini cart?

Comment: @NigelBoulton did you get the solution? I am also facing same prob.